# Background color in the Card component

Tags: react-native, native-base

How do you change the background color of the entire card?

In the case of the following code, the color changes only under Item elements

The whole card remains white all the time

```
<Card style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
    <CardItem header>
        <Text>List of users</Text>
    </CardItem>
    <List
        leftOpenValue={75}
        rightOpenValue={-75}
        dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.data[0].users)}
        disableLeftSwipe = {true}
        renderRow={(item) => this._renderContent(item)}
    />
</Card>
```

Answer (score 4):

you have set background color explicitly to every cardItem

```
  <Card style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
        <CardItem header style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
            <Text>List of users</Text>
        </CardItem>
        <List
            style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}
            leftOpenValue={75}
            rightOpenValue={-75}
            dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.data[0].users)}
            disableLeftSwipe = {true}
            renderRow={(item) => this._renderContent(item)}
        />
    </Card>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't change `<Card>` background color . you must set background color to card item separately . like :

```
     <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Card>
            <CardItem style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                   //Your text here
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </Content>
      </Container>
```